# Windows 10 Mouse Issue

Tags: windows, windows-10

Dell Inspirion p55f - under windows 10 - on occasion the mouse cursor will suddenly disappear and you can see places towards the bottom of the screen where it seems like its prompting you to use it as a touch screen.

Alt-tabing into the app seems to temporarily fix the issue but it still jumps back and forth.  Mouse drivers appear up to date.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue... but sometimes even rebooting does not resolve it! The last time this happened, I had to reboot to Safe Mode, ran **SFC /scannow**, and since then the cursor has returned, though SFC found no issue.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with a Dell Inspiron 7568. Have you been able to fix it? I've been googling around for hours.

Comment: @emzero I haven't - its actually my better half's computer - I'm a mac/linux person =)